# macOS 10.15 Terminal - unlink gets "Operation not permitted"

Tags: terminal, zsh, macos-catalina, unlink

zsh; Terminal has Full Disk Access permission in System Preferences.

```
/usr/bin % ls -alF python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  75 Jul 12 11:48 python@ -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin % sudo unlink python
Password:
unlink: python: Operation not permitted
/usr/bin %
```

EDIT by OP to add this terminal transcript:

```
~ % whence python
/usr/bin/python
~ % echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/brec/.rvm/bin
~ % ls -alF /usr/local/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 brec  admin  24 Dec 11 10:45 /usr/local/bin/python@ -> /usr/local/bin/python3.8
~ % python

WARNING: Python 2.7 is not recommended.
```

NOTE: /usr/local/bin/python3.8 does not exist.

Comment: This is likely an issue with the root file system being mounted read-only, which renders individual file permissions moot.

Comment: @chepner If that's the issue, how would I re-target the symlink?

Comment: Maybe try and `sudo chown` the symlink.

Comment: chown: python: Operation not permitted :(

Comment: You don't. Leave system-installed stuff alone. Put the directory containing the version you want to use in your `PATH` variable ahead of `/usr/bin`, or use virtual environments.

Comment: Thanks @chepner. My PATH starts with: /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin and /usr/local/bin/python is a symlink to /usr/local/bin/python3.8. But `whence python` returns /usr/bin/python which is a symlink to a python2.7. `alias` returns no alias for `python`. Why does the python command  resolve to /usr/bin/python ?

Comment: @brec : I think this is a Catalina issue. Apple provides at least since Mojave the MacOS in a way, that even _root_ can not do everything in /usr/bin.

Comment: If `whence python` return `/usr/bin/python`, then either `PATH` isn't what you think it is, your shell's path cache needs to be refreshed, or `python` isn't installed in `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: @chepner please see the terminal transcript I added to the question.

Answer (score 3):

On recent macOS versions, System Integrity Protection (SIP) prevents modification of files in several locations, including `/usr/bin`. Because some parts of macOS use Python, you cannot modify the symlink at `/usr/bin/python` - if you did, it might break some parts of the OS which depend on that specific version of Python. You cannot modify SIP-protected files even as root.

Your best bet is to install a separate version of Python and make sure your `PATH` environment variable is set accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I unlinked /usr/local/bin/python and then created a soft link /usr/local/bin/python to the version of python I want the `python` command to execute.