# MacOs Monterey Python3 as default

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, terminal, macos-monterey

I am currently trying to change my default Python version to Python3. This proves to be harder than expected.
I have already tried the following things:

1. I have tried to change the alias by doing `alias python python3` but this seems to just change it for the running Terminal session
2. I have installed Python3 again with Homebrew and tried to change the directory within the zshellruncommand by defining it myself and editing it in vim
   to be honest I don't really understand the process and just followed along with a tutorial but it didn't work.
3. I tried the command `ln -s -f /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python` to change the directories but it returned `ln: /usr/bin/python: Operation not permitted`

to deal with this problem I have already given the Terminal full access to the local harddrive but it is still not working properly

Hoping for some advise,
thanks in advance

Comment: Until the OS itself decides that `python` should refer to a Python 3 interpreter, you are better off working in a virtual environment created from whichever Python you want to use.

Comment: for `ln -s` you want to try with `/usr/local/bin/python` instead. you cannot modify `/usr/bin/python` on mac - see also the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65297862/10237506).

Comment: Activation of said virtual environment can be done from `.zshrc` so that it's automatically available in any interactive instance of `zsh`.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure the installed version is linked:

```
brew link python
```

then on your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` (`.zshrc` if you're using zsh) write this:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/python@X.Y/libexec/bin:$PATH"
```

change `X` and `Y` to your python version

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easier to just change your user shell environment instead of changing the system level environment.

```
vi ~/.bash
```

Then type

```
alias python=python3
```

Save your file by pressing `Esc` -> type `:wq`

Update your shell environment

```
source ~/.bash
```

Check your Python version.

```
python -V
```

Final result

```
Python 3.9.10
```

This works in my past few versions MacOS.

Comment: `/usr/bin/env python` doesn't work with aliases

Comment: This solution works well if you have Python3 installed, but it wasn't installed from Homebrew.